# How to drive 0-85mA proportional solenoid valve with WAGO PLC 4-20mA or 0-10V?

Tags: plc, 4-20ma

I am looking to use an SMC PVQ valve. I need to drive it using a WAGO PLC. Common modules for the WAGO PLC are 4-20mA and 0-10V. How can I do it using these or any other module/method?

Very little comes up when I search; is this not a common problem?

[SMC PVQ datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/1ef9/0900766b816bf839.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably expect you to use a driver (an additional module specific to the type of actuator) to operate the valve. Or, more likely, a custom controller which supplies the current range into an inductive load with adequate voltage compliance.

The 0-10V and 4-20mA are *signal* standards and are not intended to drive a solenoid directly.

Of course one could design and build such a thing, but usually PLC users want to purchase compatible interoperable products with warranties and service into the future years or decades.

SMC parlance refers to that as an "amplifier" and they offer combined units such as VY1 that accept a signal 1-5V and require a 24VDC power supply.  I would expect that the PVQ series is designed for use in devices with integrated control electronics rather than a general industrial PLC. By having the OEM supply the 'amplifier' the cost can be lowered for the PVQ series, appropriate for larger production runs of special devices.